# Does the group $G$ have an element of order $6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Is there any easy way to check is there any element of order $6$ in a group $(G,\cdot),$ where $$G=\left\{A_{x,y}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 x+7y & 5y \\
 -10y & x-7y \\
\end{bmatrix},
\in M_2(\mathbb{R}) \ \middle|\ x^2+y^2\neq0\right\}$$
or do I have to find $A_{x,y}^6$ and solve the equation $A_{x,y}^6=I$?

Comment: Setting $x = -1$ and $y = 0$ gives us an obvious example of such an element

Comment: Every element of the group is invertible. (Why?) If $A$ is of order $6$, then it's determinant to the sixth power equals one. (Why?) Can this $A$ exist?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Your example won't work as its *order* has to be $6$. In your example, the square of the matrix itself will be $I$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani True, I was thinking about solutions to $X^6 = I$ rather than elements of order $6$ I suppose.

Comment: I thought this was a reasonably interesting question, and I cannot imagine why it has been closed.

Answer (score 8):

Your group is the set of the matrices of the form $xI + yA$ (subject to the constraint $x^2 + y^2 \neq 0$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and
$$
A = \pmatrix{7&5\\ -10&-7}.
$$
Note that $A^2 = -I$. With that, we can deduce that the map $\phi:(G,\cdot) \to (\Bbb C^*,\cdot)$ given by
$$
\phi(xI + yA) = x + yi
$$
is an isomorphism. Thus, it suffices to solve the equation $z^6 = 1$ for $z \in \Bbb C^*$.  In particular, with De Moivre's Theorem, we can see that taking $x = \cos(2 \pi/6)$ and $y = \sin(2 \pi /6)$ gives us an element of order $6$.

Comment: Oh, that's neat!

Answer (score 3):

**The intuition**:

Note that $\det A_{x, y} = x^2 + y^2$. For $A_{x, y}^6 = I$, we must have $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. This suggests us the substitution $(x, y) = (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$.

---

For $\theta \in \Bbb R$, define $A_\theta$ as
$$A_\theta := A_{\sin\theta, \cos\theta}.$$

A simple calculation shows us that
$$A_\theta\cdot A_\varphi = A_{\theta + \varphi}.$$

Thus, we see that $$(A_\theta)^n = A_{n\theta}$$ for any $n \in \Bbb Z$.

It can be seen that $\theta = \pi/3$ then does the job. That is,
$$A_{\pi/3}^6 = I$$
and $$A_{\pi/3}^n \neq I$$
for any $1 \le n < 6$.

Comment: So there are exactly two solutions $x=1/2$ and $y=\pm\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: Yes. From what I wrote under **intuition**, it is clear that any such $A$ must be of the form $A_\theta$. After that, the existence of exactly two solutions follows.

Comment: I did it a different way. The minimal polynomial of such a matrix must be $x^2-x+1$, which leads to $10xy = 5y$. Since $y=0$ does not work, we get $x=1/2$, and then $y = \pm{\sqrt{3}}$ follows.

Comment: I think you should add that as an answer. (It's not immediately clear to me why that must be the minimal polynomial.)

Comment: I don't really want to write an answer. $x^2-x+1 = \Phi_n(x)$ is the sixth cyclotomic polynomial, and its (complex) roots are the two primitive sixth roots of 1. Of course that $x$ is a different $x$ from the $x$ in the  question!

Comment: Ah, I see. Your approach has the nice property that it can be easily generalised to other multiplicative subgroups of $M_2(\Bbb R)$. Quite nice!